How to upgrade work permit in Germany for one that is not tied to an employer?
In Germany I have a regular residence permit tied to my employer.
I know that after two years you can get a "free" residence permit that allows you to work for any employer without the need to change your residence permit.
I have been in Germany for 3 years now and changed employer once before reaching my 2 years, this made me go through all the hoops of the bureaucratic system again.
Now I want to get a new residence permit which is not tied to my employer.
How can I apply for this permit?
I have been looking online but I can't find any place to make an appointment.
Thank you.
